# spring boot invalid_grant Bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

i created a small service for user authentification with oauth.

The WebSecurityConfig:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }
```

The AuthorizationServer:

```
import com.oauth.server.bootstrap.PropertyConfiguration;
import com.oauth.server.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    private static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    private static final String SCOPE_DELETE = "delete";
    private static final String SCOPE_LOGIN = "login";

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";
    private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String ROLE_PRIVATE_USER = "PRIVATE";
    private static final String ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_USER = "PROFESSIONAL";

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private PropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean(name = "tokenStore")
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    /**
     * /oauth/check_token und /oauth/token_key stehen den Anwender zur Verfuegung.
     *
     * @param oauthServer
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(propertyConfiguration.getPasswordId())
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities(ROLE_ADMIN)
                .scopes(SCOPE_LOGIN)
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(propertyConfiguration.getPasswordSecret()))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(6000)
                .and()
                .withClient(propertyConfiguration.getClientCredentialsId())
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
                .authorities(ROLE_PRIVATE_USER, ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_USER)
                .scopes(SCOPE_WRITE, SCOPE_DELETE, SCOPE_READ)
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(propertyConfiguration.getClientCredentialsSecret()))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3000);
    }
```

With PropertyConfig:
i read client_id, client_secret, ... from application.properties

My Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.test.core.entities")
public class OAuthApplication {

    @Bean
    public UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl(){
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuthApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My CustomUserDetails:

```
import com.test.api.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl;
import com.test.core.entities.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import java.util.Collection;

@Configuration("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl) {
        this.userServiceImpl = userServiceImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userServiceImpl.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return !super.isBlocked();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

From `userServiceImpl.findByUsername(username)` i get an user with username: emoleumassi.

User entity class

```
@Table
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    ... another column
    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "login")
    private String password;
    ...
    // getter and setter
```

My curl:

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic ODExXXXX==' -d 'grant_type=password&username=emoleumassi&password=today'
```

I tried with encrypted password:

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic ODEXXXX' -d 'grant_type=password&username=emoleumassi&password=$2a$04$V6yvAtLlDRKKUxxf2krYJ.bkwqYymDr7.GiCsKWggbE0pRsT4dmSm'
```

My error:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Authorization: Basic XXX
> Content-Length: 55
> 
* upload completely sent off: 55 out of 55 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 
HTTP/1.1 400 
< Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 11 May 2020 19:03:54 GMT
Date: Mon, 11 May 2020 19:03:54 GMT
< Connection: close
Connection: close

< 
* Closing connection 0
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}%
```

Comment: don't you need to pass the `client_id` in the body of your `POST` request?

Comment: i use `grant_type password`